# How can I disable keyboard input in form validation for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to validate a text box so that it only takes numeric values. If the user tries to press alphabet keys, the keystrokes must be ignored, i.e nothing can be typed in.

How can this be done?

Comment: Why bother? You only care if the field is valid when the form is posted, it doesn't matter what value it has in the meantime.

Comment: Try using onchange and a hidden input.  Every time they change the input (such as copy-paste/type), it should run your script.  If the input is valid, commit the change to the hidden input, otherwise, revert to the previous state by copying from the hidden input.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your HTML page:

```
    <HTML>
   <HEAD>
   <SCRIPT language=Javascript>
      <!--
      function isNumberKey(evt)
      {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

         return true;
      }
      //-->
   </SCRIPT>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
      <INPUT id="txtChar" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" name="txtChar">
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use the `onkeypress` event.

An example which does the opposite thing (input field accepts everything but numbers) can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

Answer (score 0):

how about somthing similar to this

```
//Bind this keypress function to all of the input tags
$("input").keypress(function (evt) {
//Deterime where our character code is coming from within the event
var charCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
if (IsNumeric(charCode)) { //key's keycode
return false;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

W3C recommends using the `oninput` event, which is future proof and takes care of devices which do not have a keyboard. If your targeted browsers support `oninput`, do not use any keyboard events.

Comment: I agree, but it's not supported in IE < 9 and it's not cancellable.

Comment: @Tim It doesn't really need to be cancellable -- just adjust the element's `value` appropriately.

Comment: @user349433: Adjusting the input's value after the event has fired requires knowledge of its value immediately prior to the event and doing potentially complicated comparisons.

Comment: @Tim: Not necessarily. For example, in the case of this particular question, you could just do `this.value = this.value.replace(/\D+/g, '')`.

Answer (score 0):

With HTML5 in modern browsers you can use `<input type="number">` (see [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-number) for some examples). You'll need a fallback for older browsers though, so here you go. This works in all major browsers. It won't prevent the user from pasting or dragging in non-numeric content, however.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JCUT2/

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("foo");

textBox.onkeypress = function(e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
   if (/\D/.test(String.fromCharCode(charCode))) {
       return false;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a javascript function that you will call everytime you press a key in your textbox (with the onkeypress event).

```
  function isNumberKey(evt)
  {
     var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
     if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

     return true;
  }
```

[Code sample source](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/029c978b-aac5-472e-97a8-95b256f5febd/How-Can-I-Use-Javascript-to-Allow-Only-Numbers-to-Be-Entered-in-a-TextBox.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I recently was dealing with the same situation (but opposite -- I wanted *only* alphabetic characters). I initially considered simply using the `keypress` event, but that has a few fatal flaws:

- The user can still paste invalid data into the field;
- The user can drag invalid text into the field;
- Cancelling the keypress invalidates certain valid input (e.g., hotkeys) unless you take special care regarding meta keys (which I'm not positive is possible to do in a robust, complete, and portable manner);
- Autocomplete;
- And so on for any number of non-keyboard input methods.

Fortunately, at least Firefox and IE9 have a solution: they have an `input` event that fires for any manner of input method, whether it's a keystroke or a paste operation or whatever. IE<9 doesn't have that, but they do have a `paste` event to handle the most common use-case, but take care that it fires *before* the paste actually occurs, so you have to cancel the paste and then do most of the (IE-specific) paste work manually (just a couple of lines of code, but still a bit annoying).

I was developing for an internal network that didn't support other browsers, so I haven't researched what WebKit has available. The DOM Level 3 spec has a [`textinput` event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-textinput), but at least Firefox does not support it yet.

Comment: I'm not sure the `textInput` event is going to gain any more traction now that the `input` event exists (it's implemented in WebKit and Opera, by the way).